# How to escape {} in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have many of the input lines as seen below, where I would like to end up with an output similar to this

```
host tsclient010.tsclient {
   option host-name "tsclient010.tsclient";
   hardware ethernet 00E0C56BF96D;
   fixed-address 192.168.246.10;
}
```

fore ach of the inputs. However I run into the problem that the static content contains `{}`.

```
echo "192.168.246.10 00E0C56BF96D tsclient010.tsclient" | awk '{print
host $3 {
   option host-name "$3";
   hardware ethernet $2;
   fixed-address $1;
}
}'
```

Output:

```
awk: cmd. line:2:     host $3 {
awk: cmd. line:2:             ^ syntax error
```

I have tried to escape it by `'\{'`, but doesn't work.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to escape the needed chars?

Comment: this may help -> https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145004

Comment: `"{"` perhaps??

Comment: There are a lot of missing double quotes.

Comment: It's more than you need but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24597515/1745001 for how to generally print multi-line blocks of text within awk.

Comment: [awk and special brackets delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27427142/608639), [Escaping curly brace for Awk commands over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36951267/608639), [Escape awk special character in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40235587/608639), [Expect escaping with Awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8809461/608639), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Text inside double quotes is text. Text not inside double quotes is awk script.
2. The newline delimeters awk commands.

You can:

```
echo "192.168.246.10 00E0C56BF96D tsclient010.tsclient" | awk '{
    print "host "$3" {"
    print "option host-name \""$3"\";"
    print "hardware ethernet "$2";"
    print "fixed-address "$1";"
    print "}"
}'
```

or

```
echo "192.168.246.10 00E0C56BF96D tsclient010.tsclient" | awk '{
    print "host "$3" {\noption host-name \""$3"\";\nhardware ethernet "$2";\nfixed-address "$1";\n}" }'
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to escape the braces.  You need to quote them and escape the double quotes.

```
awk '{printf "\
host %s {\
   option host-name \"%s\";\
   hardware ethernet %s;\
   fixed-address %s;\
}\n", $3, $3, $2, $1
}'
```